# Необходима помощь с SQL запросом

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос на создание функции:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `ban`(parip VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS tinyint(1) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE vid INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE iip INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT INET_ATON(parip); 
banlist SELECT id INTO vid FROM banlist WHERE ip=iip LIMIT 1; 
INSERT INTO banlist (ip) VALUES (iip);
ELSE 
UPDATE banlist SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = vid;
END IF; 
RETURN vid=0; 
END
```

выводит вот такую ошибку:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: DELIMITER ихде? ну и синтаксические ошибки бы вместе с опечатками - поправить.

Comment: "DELIMITER -;" А можно немного поточнее где тут синтаксическая ошибка? просто скрипт из книги, по идеи должен работать, я перерыл уже кучу сайтов где приводятся примеры по написанию функций при помощи SQL и вот он ругается на "DECLARE", хотя во всех примерах он так же применяться.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас синтаксическая ошибка.
В теле функции используется конструкция if-else-end if
так вот самого IF нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если отправляете SQL запрос через PHP, то попробуйте написать весь запрос в одну строку. MySQL может неправильно обрабатывать перенос строки.

Comment: Там просто синтаксис неправильный.